# Cmake build in specific order

Tags: java, java-native-interface, cmake

I'm trying to create a JNI jar with CMake. For that the following has to be done in the appropriate order:

1. compile .class files
2. generate .h headers
3. build native library
4. jar everything

where

1. is done with `add_jar()` (I prefered that at custom_command)
2. is done with `add_custom_command(TARGET ...)`
3. is done with `add_library()`
4. is done with `add_custom_command(TARGET ...)` (because -C option is not supported by add_jar)

How can I ensure that the proper order is followed? I get errors sometimes on the first run.

`add_custom_command` has a `POST`/`PRE` build option, but `add_jar` and `add_library` does not. The `add_custom_command` that does not have the argument `TARGET` has the `DEPENDS` option, should I use that?

Is there a way of telling `add_library` to wait for the 2. custom command to have been ran?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the error is that you're calling `add_library` with source files which don't yet exist during the first run of CMake?

If so, you can set the [`GENERATED`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_sf%3aGENERATED) property on those source files using the [`set_source_files_properties`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aset_source_files_properties) command.  This lets CMake know that it's OK for those files to not exist at configure-time (when CMake runs), but that they will exist at build-time.

To ensure that the `add_jar` command executes before `add_library`, create a dependency on the `add_jar` target using [`add_dependencies`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_dependencies).  To ensure that the `add_custom_command` command executes before `add_library`, have the custom command use the [`TARGET ... PRE_BUILD`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) options.

For example, if your list of sources for the lib is held in a variable called `${Srcs}`, you can do:

```
# Allow 'Srcs' to not exist at configure-time
set_source_files_properties(${Srcs} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
add_library(MyLib ${Srcs})

# compile .class files
add_jar(MyJarTarget ...)

# generate .h headers
add_custom_command(TARGET MyLib PRE_BUILD COMMAND ...)

# Force 'add_jar' to be built before 'MyLib'
add_dependencies(MyLib MyJarTarget)
```

Comment: Awesome. That did it: add_dependencies and knowing that PRE/POST build kind of 'unite' the custom command with the target passed by argument).
Actually, what I worked for me is add_jar,then custom_command javah with POST_BUILD on add_jar target, then add_library dependant on the add_jar target and finally custom command POST_BUILD on the library.
I am trully happy, I didn't really think it was possible cmake+java

Comment: ah! and thanks for the set_source_files_properties. I didn't like listing the headers manually as their filenames are autogenerated as well. But since while the include directory is known, that's not an issue (unless you're under VS and want the headers on the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167154/listing-header-files-in-visual-studio-c-project-generated-by-cmake )