# Get Dependent Header Files from C++ Source File

Tags: c++, cmake

How do you get all dependent header files from a source file in CMake?

My question is based on this : [Listing header files in Visual Studio C++ project generated by cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167154/listing-header-files-in-visual-studio-c-project-generated-by-cmake)

In that question, the answer is to list all the header files to the target. One of the comment says that it is possible to get all the C++ dependent header files from the source file because CMake does know about it.

Comment: well, gcc has `-M` (or `-MM` to skip "system" headers) mode which generates Makefile-style dependencies for a given source file.

Comment: It seems that MSVC supports `/showIncludes' switch: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396