# undefined reference to `SDL_Init' in an external library

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, clion

so i am making a class in an external library to use it in an SDL project.
**when using a single file sdl is linked correctly and works fine**.But when i use the external library
i get *Screen.cpp:7: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'* i use main.cpp, Screen.cpp and Screen.h 
this is **Screen.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_CLASSSDL_SCREEN_H
#define TEST_CLASSSDL_SCREEN_H
#include "C:/dev/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/SDL.h"
    class Screen {
    public:
        void init();
    };
#endif
```

and this is Screen.cpp

```
#include "Screen.h"
void Screen::init() {
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt (used by clion and very important here)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test_classSDL)
set(SDL2_LIB_DIR C:/dev/i686-w64-mingw32/lib)
include_directories(C:/dev/i686-w64-mingw32/include)

add_definitions(-DSDL_MAIN_HANDLED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}  ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2.dll.a
        ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2main.a ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2_image.dll.a main.cpp Screen.cpp Screen.h)
```

and thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: You can try by using the find scripts [here](https://github.com/tcbrindle/sdl2-cmake-scripts). I don't think you really want absolute paths in `#include`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Screen.h` is not needed in `add_executable`.
2. To tell compiler which library your target (i.e. executable) should link to, use [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Replace your last `add_executable` statement with:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp Screen.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2.dll.a ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2main.a
  ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2_image.dll.a)
```

Comment: ***Screen.h is not needed in add_executable.*** For some IDEs (like Visual Studio) it's desirable to add header files to the target. The reason if you don't the header does not appear as part of the project in the IDE (making navigation more difficult).With that said I do realize this question was tagged as clion

Comment: @drescherjm Can you please give a reference about that? I haven't worked with Visual Studio or Clion.

Comment: Related to that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167154/listing-header-files-in-visual-studio-c-project-generated-by-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167154/listing-header-files-in-visual-studio-c-project-generated-by-cmake)