# How to use all *.c files in a directory with the Cmake build system?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I want to find all .c files under a directory and add them all to SRC files to compile in cmake. How can I do this in CMakeList.txt.

for regular makefiles I can create

```
SPECIFIED_SRC_FILE  = $(foreach d,$(SPECIFIED_SRC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*,*.c)))
```

but I couldn't get how to do something like this in CMakeList.txt.

Comment: Note that "collect all source files with glob" is **not recommended** in CMake: *We do not recommend using `GLOB` to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no `CMakeLists.txt` file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.* -- from [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/file.html)

Comment: @FranklinYu is there an alternative that does not require writing every file name manually?

Comment: @Ciro If you want to avoid writing every file name, then I think `foreach` mentioned by OP is the way to go. However, CMake team seems to recommend *manually writing every file name*.

Comment: *manually writing every file name* ??? Seriously ?

Comment: Is there anything in the new versions of CMake that allow to auto-find the source files whenever you run make?

Comment: @kebs Yes, seriously.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this:

> `AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY`
>
> Find all source files in a directory.
>
> ```
> AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(dir VARIABLE)
> ```
>
> Collects the names of all the source files in the specified directory
>   and stores the list in the variable provided. This command is intended
>   to be used by projects that use explicit template instantiation.
>   Template instantiation files can be stored in a "Templates"
>   subdirectory and collected automatically using this command to avoid
>   manually listing all instantiations.
>
> It is tempting to use this command to avoid writing the list of source
>   files for a library or executable target. While this seems to work,
>   there is no way for CMake to generate a build system that knows when a
>   new source file has been added. Normally the generated build system
>   knows when it needs to rerun CMake because the CMakeLists.txt file is
>   modified to add a new source. When the source is just added to the
>   directory without modifying this file, one would have to manually
>   rerun CMake to generate a build system incorporating the new file.

Comment: make sure and read the last part that starts with "It is tempting to use this command to avoid..."

Comment: @SaoPauloooo, as it's written next, "there is no way for Cmake to generate a buildsystem that knows when a new source file has been added". This command is the most close answer to OP's question. Fine for me.

Comment: examples please

Comment: I miss more detailed explanation on how to use AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY. Should I use ""?, where do I use the VARIABLE?, etc

Comment: @piedramania - you shouldn't use it at all. See my answer. Even if you choose to go the inadvisable path of using globs, there are less harmful ways than this.

Comment: @AlexReinking It's been 13 years since I wrote this answer and I've spent them writing out the lists of sources explicitly in my CMakeLists. However, I have to point out that "The only correct answer is to not do this." isn't an answer to the question that is being asked; it is your opinion. It should be a comment.

Comment: @Catherine - I am trying to help piedramania who commented on your answer _one month_ ago, not 13 years. Your issue with my answer is apparently one of phrasing: "There is no way to do this that provides all of a small set of reasonable baseline behaviors" is true, but less snappy. You also ignore the rest of my answer which actually goes into detail. Are you engaging me in good faith, or to provoke?

Comment: @Catherine - I reread the [StackOverflow Help article on answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) which reads "Your answer can say 'don’t do that,' but it should also say 'try this instead.'". In response to you and the last piece of this quote I have made explicit in my answer the consequence of its reasoning: that one should list their sources explicitly.

Comment: @AlexReinking I simply don't consider "don't do X" a legitimate answer to "how do I do X?". All it does is show one's arrogance, presupposing that you know better than them.

Comment: @Catherine - I disagree. When someone asks "How do I shoot myself in the foot?" unawares, telling them not to is an act of compassion, not a display of arrogance. Regardless, the StackOverflow rules explicitly endorse my style of answer, so I encourage you to [raise your concerns on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you wish to litigate further.

Comment: @AlexReinking I think comparing a minor cache invalidation bug to being shot in the foot is being far too dramatic in an attempt to obscure the fact that it's not actually a huge deal to not do this maintenance task in the exact way you think it should be done.

Comment: @Catherine - That's a really common idiom.

Answer (score 91):

How about the good old globbing?

```
FILE(GLOB MyCSources *.c)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(MyExecutable ${MyCSources})
```

Comment: This works great, but does it avoid the caveat (that CMake won't know when new files are added) in the other two answers?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You will still need to re-run CMake once a new file is added.

Comment: (which ended up being fine for my needs... easier than editing the CMakeList every time you add a source file)

Comment: There's also `GLOB_RECURSE` if you want to find the files recursively.

Comment: wait a sec, if you make a big list manually, CMake *still* doesn't know you added a new file; and also, should headers be added too?

Comment: If you manually type out each name, adding a file requires changing the CMakeLists.txt file. This will cause CMake to regenerate your project. You can glob the header files into another variable or into the same variable. ADD_EXECUTABLE doesn't care about header files. As long as the headers can be found in the  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.

Comment: @DavidFong - CONFIGURE_DEPENDS is inherently unreliable and its use is not condoned even by its own developers. Please see my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 22):

**`GLOB_RECURSE` recursive example**

It basically makes the `*` also go into subdirectories:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*.c")
add_executable(main ${SOURCES})
```

And then our sources could be located for example as:

```
src/main.c
src/d/a.c
src/d/a.h
```

And `main.c` uses `#include "d/a.h"` and `a.c` uses `#include "a.h"`.

Using `GLOB_RECURSE` on the CMake toplevel (i.e. `"*.c"` instead of `"src/*.c"`) is likely a bad idea, as it can pick up `.c` files generated by CMake itself which are placed under `build/`.

Runnable example [on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/7c954cf5e837daf48f5cb94d46351d8fc068f3f1/cmake/multi_file_recursive/CMakeLists.txt).

Answer (score 20):

The ***only*** correct answer is to ***not do this***. This has been detailed in [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538444/2137996) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060061/2137996) here on SO. I will summarize here, in decreasing order of importance.

1. The developers have [*explicitly* stated<sup>1</sup>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) that it is wrong to do this. That should give you pause. If you encounter an issue, the developers will likely not be receptive to fixing it for you, but will rather tell you to list your sources.
2. The `aux_source_directory` function is outright incorrect since it cannot detect changes in the filesystem. For the same reason, using `file(GLOB` or `file(GLOB_RECURSE` without `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` is outright incorrect.
3. `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` is not guaranteed to work. (See point 1)

   1. In fact, [it was buggy](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1724#issuecomment-677730694) on Windows before Ninja 1.10.2.
   2. It also breaks dry-run workflows since the glob checks run in a parent build and the child (real) build is invoked recursively.
4. If globbing fails, you will have a difficult time figuring out which extra source file got added or removed.
5. Globbing, especially recursive globbing, can be slow and gets worse the more files you have. Ext4's performance is typically acceptable, but NTFS's is bad, especially through Linux drivers. See: https://github.com/alexreinking/cmake-glob-performance/
6. Globbing is particularly likely to fail when doing git bisects, switching branches, or performing other source control operations that move file timestamps backward.

Explicitly list your sources instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here's what the CMake developers have to say about it:

> **Note:** We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate. The `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` flag may not work reliably on all generators, or if a new generator is added in the future that cannot support it, projects using it will be stuck. Even if `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` works reliably, there is still a cost to perform the check on every rebuild.

Comment: So what's the solution? List all files manually?

Comment: When many developers drop a testcase file in a single directory, adding a line in CMakeLists.txt always lead to merge-conflicts. And then every developer has to rebase his branch. Globbing (and re-configure on add/delete) is the only option in that case.

Comment: @sanjivgupta - I have _never_ had that problem. Are you listing sources all on a single line?

Comment: Hi @AlexReinking e.g. In the tests/CMakeLists.txt developer1 on line 10: add_subdirectory(footestdir). Developer2 on line 10: add_subdirectory(bartestdir)

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida yes. How hard is it?

Comment: @sanjivgupta if that's the hardest git conflict you ever have to resolve then lucky you. How often are you adding and removing .c files?

Comment: @MarcH I agree manually listing is the best. I ran into conflicts when many developers working their test in individual cmake files appending a filename to one top-level cmake file. But that's normal in collaborative development.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you have two options. Let's assume you the folder structure something similar to this.

```
├── autopilot
            │   ├── _AutoPilot.cpp
            │   ├── _AutoPilot.h
            │   └── action
            │       ├── ActionBase.cpp
            │       ├── ActionBase.h
            │       ├── APcopter
            │       │   ├── APcopter_avoid.cpp
            │       │   ├── APcopter_avoid.h
```

If you are to use `AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY` you have to add CMakeLists.txt each one of sub directories. Then you have to include and link all those subdirectories. This is quite a difficult task. So you can you GLOB and do the job very easily. This is how it is done.

```
  file(GLOB autopilot_sources ./**.cpp ./**.c)
  SET( autopilot ${autopilot_sources})
```

If you want to create a library using above source code this is the command:

```
  ADD_LIBRARY ( autopilot  ${autopilot_sources})
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( autopilot)
```

If you want to create an executable file using above source code this is the command:

```
 ADD_EXECUTABLE(autopilot ${autopilot_sources})
```

Comment: file(GLOB autopilot_sources ./**.cpp ./**.c) might be a little simpler at handling multiple depths

Comment: Yeap seems to be. Just edit my answer and some examples

Comment: Is your method safe from the possible pit fall of blind Build System? (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655165/5595995)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY` as @whitequark described, but it won't really work as you expect, as CMake will be unable to determine when new files are added (which is kind of the whole point with using a wildcard).

Comment: AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY is performed well for now. Thank you so much.

AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(${PROJECT_INC_DIR}control/src  CTR_SOURCES)
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${EXE_NAME} ${CTR_SOURCES} )