# Recursive CMake search for header and source files

Tags: build, cmake, build-process, build-automation

I am new to CMake and would like to ask if somebody can help in the following problem.

I have C++ source and header files in their respective folders and now, I want to make a CMake text file that recursively searches for them.

Currently, I am doing it in this way:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(CarDetectorDAISY)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS *.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HDRS *.h)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(stereo_framework  ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(stereo_framework)
```

This creates my *CarDetectorDAISY.sln* solution file and when I try to build it, it shows 
an error that header files are not found (No such file or directory).

It would be really grateful if someone can please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Checkout this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745627/have-cmake-recursively-scan-folders

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're probably missing one or more [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:include_directories) calls.  Adding headers to the list of files in the `add_executable` call doesn't actually add then to the compiler's search path - it's a convenience feature whereby they are only added to the project's folder structure in IDEs.

So, in your root, say you have /my_lib/foo.h, and you want to include that in a source file as

```
#include "my_lib/foo.h"
```

Then in your CMakeLists.txt, you need to do:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

If, instead you just want to do

```
#include "foo.h"
```

then in the CMakeLists.txt, do

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib)
```

I should mention that [`file(GLOB...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:file) is not the recommended way to gather your list of sources - you should really just add each file explicitly in the CMakeLists.txt.  By doing this, if you add or remove a source file later, the CMakeLists.txt is modified, and CMake automatically reruns the next time you try and build.  From the docs for `file`:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

Comment: I'm on the fence on this one.  I agree with your point, but the counter-argument is usually that it's pretty easy to do `ls` or `dir` to get the initial list of sources, and then you're normally just adding one or two files at a time thereafter.  It's pretty safe to glob if you're working on your own.  If you're part of a team, you have to "train" the team to always run CMake after adding a file or updating from a remote VCS in case a file was added by another team member.

Comment: Better to use `target_include_directories` instead of `include_directories`, as the latter is global and discouraged by modern CMake practices.

Answer (score 10):

My answer is mostly a hack, but I find it useful if you don't want to add all dir manually.

This macro will recursively scan all sub-directories (and their sub-directories, etc ...). If a directory contains a header (.h) file, it will append its path to the `return_list`. This list can then be used with `target_include_directories`.

```
MACRO(HEADER_DIRECTORIES return_list)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list *.h)
    SET(dir_list "")
    FOREACH(file_path ${new_list})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(dir_path ${file_path} PATH)
        SET(dir_list ${dir_list} ${dir_path})
    ENDFOREACH()
    LIST(REMOVE_DUPLICATES dir_list)
    SET(${return_list} ${dir_list})
ENDMACRO()
```

Usage:

```
HEADER_DIRECTORIES(header_dir_list)

list(LENGTH header_dir_list header_dir_list_count)
message(STATUS "[INFO] Found ${header_dir_list_count} header directories.")

target_include_directories(
    my_program
    PUBLIC
    ${header_dir_list} # Recursive
)
```

Macro credit: [Christoph](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-June/050674.html)

Tested with Cmake 3.10

Comment: this is golden. you just saved me a lot of time, my friend, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Just to further clarify one point in Fraser's answer:

Headers should not be passed to `ADD_EXECUTABLE`.

The reason is that the intended compilation command on Linux for example is just:

```
gcc main.c mylib.c
```

and not:

```
gcc main.c mylib.c mylib.h
```

The C pre-processor then parses `mylib.c`, and sees a `#include "mylib.h"`, and uses it's search path for those files.

By using `include_directories` instead, we modify the cpp preprocessor search path instead, which is the correct approach. In GCC, this translates to adding the `-I` flag to the command line:

```
gcc -Inew/path/to/search/for/headers main.c mylib.c
```

Comment: It may come in handy to list headers in the `target_sources()` command, as headers listed as sources won't get compiled directly on their own, but adding them will list those headers in project’s file within IDEs, even if no source file #includes them directly.

Note: Obviously this is just complementary to using the `include_directories()` command