# Undefined symbol for architecture error

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I have a curious case of the "undefined symbol for architecture", which admittedly has been asked here numerous times but I feel the reason behind my error is more fundamental.

I am new to C++ and have a very basic program using no third party libraries, hence I do not understand why it would be, as other answers to this question have alluded, related to a mixture of libraries built with different compilers.

Here is my code in it's entirety

**src/myTest.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point3D.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace lspsm;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Point3D p(1,2,3);
    cout << p.getX() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**src/Point3D.h**

```
#ifndef Point3D_H
#define Point3D_H

namespace lspsm {

class Point3D {
    int p_values [3];
public:
    Point3D(int x, int y, int z);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    int getZ();
};

}

#endif
```

**src/Point3D.cpp**

```
#include Point3D_H

namespace lspsm {

Point3D::Point3D(int x, int y, int z) {
    p_values[0] = x;
    p_values[1] = y;
    p_values[2] = z;
}

int Point3D::getX() {
    return p_values[0];
}

int Point3D::getY() {
    return p_values[1];
}

int Point3D::getZ() {
    return p_values[2];
}

}
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable(myTest myTest.cpp)
```

In *build* I run

```
cmake ../src
make
```

This worked fine before I started using the `Point3D` class inside `main` but now I see the error

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/mh/dev/CPP/build
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable myTest
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "lspsm::Point3D::getX()", referenced from:
      _main in myTest.o
  "lspsm::Point3D::Point3D(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in myTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Have I written the class implementation wrong for `Point3D`?

I'm running this on OS X Sierra with make 3.81.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CMakeLists.txt`, you need to also add `Point3D.cpp` to the list of `add_executable` sources:

```
add_executable(myTest myTest.cpp Point3D.cpp)
```

Comment: this worked! thank you. is there a way to reference all files in a dir, if I end up with lots of classes.

Comment: I don't do that in my own projects, but this post seems to have some reasonable suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110795/how-to-find-all-c-files-for-cmake-build-system