# how to create subprocess of CMake command with python?

Tags: python, c, cmake, terminal, subprocess

**So i am using cmake command to build and run certain stuff now if I run this command directly in shell it works**

and build file

but if I run it inside python with the help of subprocess nothing is happening.

code cmake file

[image]

now to run this I used the following command in terminal
$ mkdir build && cd build

$ cmake .. && make

it totally works

now in python first command is working and the build directory is formed
but cmake is not working.

[image]

Comment: [Do not use `aux_source_directory` for getting lists of source files.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65191951/2137996) It is outright incorrect.

Comment: Also do not use `include_directories`. Use `target_include_directories(COSMO PRIVATE inc)` instead.

Comment: Using **images** for code is **discouraged** on Stack Overflow. Please, [edit] the question and paste the code into it as **text**. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `subprocess.run` does not maintain the current working directory between calls. so `cmake ..` runs in the directory *above* the `build` folder, not *in* the `build` folder. You should use the following two commands, instead anyway:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build
$ cmake --build build
```

The first command tells CMake to use the current directory (`.`) for sources (`-S`) and to use the directory `build` for build outputs (`-B`). It will create that directory if it does not exist.

The second command asks CMake to invoke the native build tool (in your case `make`) in the given directory (`build`).

You should be able to paste those into your `subprocess.run` calls and have it work *without* `shell=True`.