# CMake How to access headers and source files in a different folder

Tags: cmake

I have a code repository like image below. I'm trying to add a new standalone executable. The `main.cpp` and `CMakeLists.txt` files are located in `folder4` and `main.cpp` requires code from `folder3`.

At the moment I'm using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(Standalone)

# add the executable
add_executable(StandaloneExe main.cpp)
```

Should I now use `file( GLOB SRCS *.cpp *.h )` to retrieve the headers and source files from `folder3`?

I just want the simplest way of generating this executable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I now use file( GLOB SRCS *.cpp *.h ) to retrieve the headers and source files from folder3?

No, you should *never* use `GLOB` to get sources. See my answer here for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65191951/2137996

> I just want the simplest way of generating this executable.

Put your CMakeLists.txt in the root instead. Then just write:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(Standalone)

# add the executable
add_executable(
  StandaloneExe
  folder2/folder4/main.cpp
  folder1/folder3/a.cpp
  folder1/folder3/b.cpp
)

# Might need this, maybe not, depending on your includes
target_include_directories(
  StandaloneExe
  PRIVATE 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/folder1/folder3"
)
```

If you *absolutely cannot* move your lists file, then you can use absolute paths:

```
add_executable(
  StandaloneExe
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../folder2/folder4/main.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../folder1/folder3/a.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../folder1/folder3/b.cpp
)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. May I ask what is the condition on the includes? And I can't put the CMakaeLists in the root because there already is one there for another executable. This is just a small standalone for part of the system.

Comment: If you had, eg. `#include <a.h>` in main.cpp, you might need to set the include path.

Comment: I've just tried target_include_directories and I get Cannot specify include directories for target ........ which is not built by this project

Comment: Basically I'm trying to create a standalone executable which is going to run a small subset of the code base. That's why I wanted to locate the CMakeList and main.cpp within a subfolder

Comment: @user997112 I can't say why that would happen without seeing your CMakeLists.txt, but it's likely just a typo. Or somehow you called it before add_executable