# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Lib\lua.lib'

Tags: dll, cmake, lua

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(lua)

aux_source_directory(${LUA_SRC_DIR} LUA_SOURCES)

list(REMOVE_ITEM LUA_SOURCES ${LUA_SRC_DIR}/lua.c ${LUA_SRC_DIR}/luac.c)

add_definitions(-DBUILD_LUA_AS_DLL -DLUA_LIB)

add_library(lua SHARED ${LUA_SOURCES})
```

seems nothing wrong, why this happen?

Comment: It is unlikely that given code emits the error shown in the title. Please, add surround messages for the error message you get, so it will be clear which build step generates that message.

Comment: **Do not use `aux_source_directory`**. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65191951/2137996).