# CMake file GLOB_RECURSE with complex globs

Tags: cmake, glob

I would like to use `file(GLOB_RECURSE...` as follows:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE _tmp_files
     LIST_DIRECTORIES false
     "${mydir}/*.cpp|${mydir}/*.h")
```

This -- along with variations such as `${mydir}/*{.cpp,.h}` -- yields an empty list.
However, this works as expected -- produces all the `*.cpp` files in the `${mydir}` along with its subdirectories:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE _tmp_files
     LIST_DIRECTORIES false
     "${mydir}/*.cpp")
```

So, does the `file(` feature in `CMake` indeed support "full" globbing? In particular, how to glob for a pattern `{*.cpp,*.h}` using `file(`?

Comment: [Do not glob for sources in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65191951/2137996)

Comment: Globbing/wildcards are generally not well liked by the CMake maintainers (even Meson doesn't like it):

- https://discourse.cmake.org/t/is-glob-still-considered-harmful-with-configure-depends/808
- https://discourse.cmake.org/t/add-globbing-support-to-target-sources/3749
- https://mesonbuild.com/FAQ.html#why-cant-i-specify-target-files-with-a-wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, does the file( feature in CMake indeed support "full" globbing?

Yes.

Your expressions do not work the way you expect them to work. `{..,..}` is not a way to match multiple suffixes in glob, `{` `,` `}` are matched literally and have no special meaning in glob. `"${mydir}/*.cpp|${mydir}/*.h"` is not an OR in glob - `|` is matched literally, it has no special meaning in glob. See `man 7 glob`.

> how to glob for a pattern {*.cpp,*.h} using file(?

Write it twice.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE _tmp_files
     LIST_DIRECTORIES false
     ${mydir}/*.cpp
     ${mydir}/*.h
)
```