# Difference between invoking `ninja` directly vs through `cmake --build`

Tags: cmake, ninja

Follow the commands:

First I do:

```bash
cmake -G Ninja ..
```

then:

```bash
cmake --build . -j10
```

or:

```bash
ninja -j10
```

What is the difference between them? Are there pros or cons between them?

Comment: `cmake --build` just calls `ninja` for you

Comment: cmake is a build system; you define how your project should be put together. It *can* create `ninja.build` files for you. Ninja will do the building. `cmake --build` just calls the builder for you. This should have been explained.

Comment: `cmake --build . -j10` will build with 10 threads using whatever project type / build method is enabled by the generator setting that was set on the cmake -G

Comment: ***what is the best command*** It does not really matter in your case however `ninja -j10` is less characters to type..

Answer (score 14):

When you run `cmake -G Ninja..` it essentially means that you are using a [build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941536/what-is-a-cmake-generator) namely [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/).  For better understanding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941536/what-is-a-cmake-generator/61651241#61651241) visual depiction will further clarify. Furthermore, the `Ninja` in `cmake -G Ninja..` will generate Ninja build files.

Regarding your question what is the difference between `cmake --build . -j10` and `ninja -j10`?

Apparently there is no difference in your case as you have already run `cmake -G Ninja ..` previously.  Both `cmake --build . -j10` and `ninja -j10` are fine in your case.

To further clarify, the `-j` means "*number of jobs*". And to put it more precisely, it is `-jN`. Where `N` explicitly sets "*number of jobs*" to run in parallel. This means your build will use `10` [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633074/set-the-number-of-threads-in-a-cmake-build/50883555) as you have `-j10`

Comment: what would be the difference if the `-GNinja` option was not present? What's the advantage of using a builder like ninja, or using none?

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, there is no practical difference in the way it is called. However one reason you might want to use `cmake --build` is as an abstraction of the build system: you can write a script to perform the build without knowing the tool specified / used to generate the build scripts.