# How to Specify the Compiler and To Compile Different Main Functions

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

My project is quite simple but I like to keep files in different folders for clarity. For instance I have three folders.

- An `Output` folder that contains all the classes used for the output. (for now only Output.cc and Output.h).
- A `Math` folder, containing all of the classes related to math. (vector.cc, vector.h, randomgen.h, randomgen.cc, etc)
- A `Tests` folder where there are different cpp files each containing a main function. (Output_test.cc, vector_test.cc, etc)

How can I create a CMake script that complies all of the different main function of the different test programs using the classes that are in different folders?
In addition, I didn't see where the compiler, and its options, are specified in a CMake file.

Answer (score 3):

## How to specify the compiler?

There are a few ways to specify the compiler you want to use.  Settings environment variables, defining compiler variables, or designating a generator.

### Settings Environment Variables

There are two ways to use environment variables to help CMake determine which compiler to use during a CMake configuration.  Using the `PATH` variable or the `CC` and `CXX` variables.

#### PATH

Make sure the path to your desired compiler is first in the list.  If you don't want to modify your path, then use the 2nd option.

#### CC & CXX

CMake reads the variables `CC` and `CXX` to determine the path for the C compiler and C++ compiler respectively.  Note that the first time CMake is configured for a project it will cache these paths, and look to the cache first for all future configurations.  So if you wish to change the compiler path, be sure to delete the cache file `CMakeCache.txt`.  As HughB [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26105829/2705293), there is a good example of this given by [Guillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275650/2705293)

### Defining Compiler Variables

Similar to using CC and CXX, there are CMake variables that can be defined at the commandline to choose the desired compiler.  They are `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`.  You can set them using the `-D` option and they use the same values as CC and CXX.  Note, just like CC and CXX these are cached after the first CMake configuration.

Example

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++4.6/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc4.6/gcc <path to src>
```

### Designating a Generator

The last way to choose the compiler is by using the -G option to select a generator.  There are numerous generators to choose and I recently answered a question about them.  I'm not going to go into too much detail about them in this answer, but you can [read my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25946781/2705293) for more details.

Example

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefile" <path to src>
```

### Don't Hardcode the Compiler

I recommend resisting the urge to "hardcode" the compiler in the CMakeLists.txt files.  CMake is meant to be compiler independent and you should be setting the compiler information external of the CMake files.  Use one of the methods mentioned above to keep your CMake files portable and to avoid confusion if yourself or someone else wants to build the project with a different compiler.

Related references. (Disclaimer: Written by me)

- [What is a CMake generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25946781/2705293)
- [Understanding the Purpose Behind CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753809/2705293)

---

## How to Compile Multiple Executables?

As HughB mentioned use `add_executables`.  You could also create separate libraries for each folder group, there are many ways to organize your project.  I'm going to keep it simple and give an example that builds two executables in the same project.

For this example I created 5 files:

include/Helloworld.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

src/HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

include/HelloWorld2.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

src/HelloWorld2.cpp

```
#include "HelloWorld2.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World2!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# This is required to compile and must contain the paths to
# all of the header files
include_directories(include)

# These are optional, but are added to be passed to the
# add_executable command so that the headers are accessible 
# from within the project
set(HW_INCLUDES include/HelloWorld.h)
set(HW_INCLUDES2 include/HelloWorld2.h)

project(HelloWorlds)

# Required sources
set(HW_SOURCES src/HelloWorld.cpp)
set(HW_SOURCES2 src/HelloWorld2.cpp)

add_executable(HelloWorld ${HW_SOURCES} ${HW_INCLUDES}) 
add_executable(HelloWorld2 ${HW_SOURCES2} ${HW_INCLUDES2})
```

When this project is built there will be two executables: HelloWorld.exe and HelloWorld2.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting the code that will be used in different program mains in a library. Use the **add_library** command to do make a library. You could have a directory hierarchy like this:

```
TopDir
   CMakeLists.txt
   MyLib
      CMakeLists.txt
      vector.cc
      vector.h
      ....
   MyExe1
      CMakeLists.txt
      main1.cc
   MyExe2
      CMakeLists.txt
      main2.cc
```

Use **add_subdirectory** in your top level cmakelists.txt to traverse the directories. In the dirs that build executables, use **add_executable** and **target_link_libraries**. If you named the library MyLib then your target_link_libraries command would look like

```
target_link_libraries( exe1 MyLib )
```

In regard to overriding the compiler, see [how to specify new gcc path for cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275348/how-to-specify-new-gcc-path-for-cmake)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this in a few moments. In the library folder i can still use many subfolders?

Comment: Yes if you are talking about multiple libraries you could have a subdir and CMakeLists.txt for each one. I guess you could also just segregate the source code into separate dirs but only build one library, but you would have to specify the relative paths to each source file like this: add_library( MyLib src1/file.cc src2/file.cc /src3/file.cc ...)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now things seems to work better (I understand better what I am doing). But when I use the cmake command a lot of "garbage" (for me, obviously not for the compiler) is generated (like the CMakefiles fliers). How do I get rid of them after the compilation succeeded?

Comment: Are you talking about the files generated to build the code? If so you should make a separate build directory and give cmake the path to the source. If you're done building the code and don't need them anymore you can just delete the build directory.

Comment: I am talking about the cake_install.cmake, CMakeCache.txt, the CMakeFiles folder and the Makefile that appear in every folder after the cmake command. How I get rid of that once I have my binaries?

Comment: @R.M. As HughB mentioned, use a separate build directory by first creating it, `cd` to it, then run `cmake <path to CMakeLists.txt>`.  You should never run `cmake .`.  That's just a bad idea.