# add_custom_command -- update dependency list over rebuilds

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

*See last status update*

**Initial conditions**

- code generator that generates set of c++ sources taking one input file as parameter
- input file may include other input files
- already solved task of getting list of output files, parsing input codegen files to get full list of codegen inputs.
   I.e. add_custom_command is provided with correct set of dependencies for the first time:

  ```
  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${generatedSources}
                     COMMAND ${codegenCommand} ARGS ${codegenArgs}
                     DEPENDS ${codegenInputFiles})
  ```

**Problem scenario**

- current system works well until someone modifies one of codegen input files to include new input file or remove include of existing one. 
   This case, it is required to update list of codegen input file provided to add_custom_command as dependencies, but I have no idea how

**What is missing**

- ability to update add_custom_command dependencies over project rebuilds

Is there any way to solve it without making full project rebuild ?

**UPDATE - Alternative (better?) problem description**

I`ve found similar not answered question on cmake mailing list, post it here for better clarity:
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.cmake.user/52279

*I am trying to get a code generation tool to behave "the same as" a C source file with respect to dependencies. By that I mean, suppose you have a C file "a.c". Because it can #include files, every time the content of `a.c` changes, its dependencies may have changed also. The dependencies get rescanned with -MMD. I would like some way to emulate this for my code generator.
First I tried add_custom_command, which takes a fixed DEPENDS list, determined at the time the custom command is defined. Concretely, I mean something like this:*

```
function(add_generated_library)
   figure_out_dependencies(deps ${ARGN})
   add_custom_command(... DEPENDS ${deps})
endfunction()
```

*But that only captures the dependencies at build-system-generation time. Every time the custom command runs, the DEPENDS list may need to change, because the changes may imply new dependencies.How should I go about doing this?*

**UPDATE 2 - Possible solution**

Following I consider as facts
 - there are voices across the web regarding cmake support of dynamic
   dependencies, which is required for smooth integration of many
   non-trivial code generation tools
 - there`s no ready-for-use optimal solution available, as what we actually need is hook to add support of custom DSL to IMPLICIT_DEPENDS

From cmake manual:

*The IMPLICIT_DEPENDS option requests scanning of implicit dependencies of an input file. The language given specifies the programming language whose corresponding dependency scanner should be used. Currently only C and CXX language scanners are supported. The language has to be specified for every file in the IMPLICIT_DEPENDS list. **Dependencies discovered from the scanning are added to those of the custom command at build time**.*

Solution below adheres (hopefully) to following criteria:

- avoid not necessary dependency scanning on rebuild
- avoid not necessary code generator run on rebuild
- allow providing cmake functions to clients to register their models and 
  generate code/create libraries from that code, without imposing any project structure requirements (i.e. no sub-project responsible for code generation, models are distributed across project hierarchy using project-specific policy)

Solution idea

It is not possible to register custom language scanner, but it is possible to reuse existing one. The idea is that dependencies / hierarchy of custom model files get reflected as hierarchy of "C" header files. Each hierarchy node get added on registering of model file and C file includes match model file includes. If model file includes get changed, C file includes get changed. Therefore, each codegen invocation would depend on just one generated C header reflecting passed model. Each reflected file will have a dependency on the model file and get touched on model file change.

**To sum up : probably, my wording is not that clear at this point, but with respect to other people needs and community helped me to investigate this problem, I will post generic solution (+ link to github or new cmake wiki page) without my project specifics once it is ready (in 1-3 days).**

Comment: Please visit [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190). You can also click on the *Editied just now* link or *Edited XXX minutes ago* link to see why the change was made. It provides the edit history.

Comment: sorry for confusion, didn`t notice your comment and decided that title was changed by some kind of script. Revert title as proposed

Comment: No problem. The site has some policies that aren't always agreeable. I happen to dislike that particular policy (I even argued against it).

Comment: What do you mean by "solve it without making a full project rebuild"? Are you trying to avoid having to re-run the cmake command to generate your build system? Does cmake cache the list of codegenInputFiles so subsequent cmake commands don't pick the changes up unless you delete the cache first?

Comment: I mean that it is understood that remove products & rebuild would work, but I would prefer to update dependency list during rebuild instead (From description of IMPLICIT_DEPENDS, it looks that I need hooks to register my language scanner, to have dependencies updated during build time like it is done for C/C++ code)

Answer (score 2):

Can you show how you initialize the variable `codegenInputFiles`? You can probably use a `file(GLOB ... )` or `file(GLOB_RECURSE ... )` command there.
See [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/file.html).

Note, though, that you will have to rerun cmake to have your command being generated. Are you working with git? Then you can have [a hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832459/getting-cmake-to-run-before-building-after-pulling-from-git) that forces a cmake call every time you pull (so that if somebody modified the `codegenInputFiles` your auto generated files will be updated).

---

After clarification of the problem, you should be able to find a workaround by using [`IMPLICIT_DEPENDS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_custom_command.html) instead of `DEPENDS`. Limitations:

1. It can only work if your input file is C/C++ (check the syntax, as you must specify the language for each file specified)
2. You might need to check your cmake version supports that command, even though it looks that it has been around for a while
3. It's only supported for Makefile generator, which sounds pretty bad...

---

**EDIT**

After some iterations, I finally got what is your problem.
I propose the following solution: separate the file generation in a separate cmake subproject. When you will build your main project (by calling make), you will trigger both cmake and make for your subproject. Calling cmake is necessary for keeping updated the dependencies, while calling make to actually build your auto-generated sources.

Here I show an example of a project and a subproject, with the project invoking cmake and make for the subproject.

Structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── a.cpp
├── build
└── subProject
    └── CMakeLists.txt
```

File content

**./CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_custom_target(subProjectTarget ALL)
add_custom_command(TARGET subProjectTarget PRE_BUILD COMMAND mkdir -p ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/subProject && cd ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/subProject && ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/subProject && make)

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/subProject)
add_executable (dummy a.cpp)
add_dependencies (dummy subProjectTarget)
```

**./a.cpp** (Note that b.h doesn't exist yet)

```
#include "b.h"

int main () {
}
```

**./SubProject/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/b.h "//I am a dummy file\n")
```

**Building the project** (using default `make`)

```
me@here:~/example/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/example/build

me@here:~/example/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target subProjectTarget
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/example/build/subProject
[  0%] Built target subProjectTarget
Scanning dependencies of target dummy
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dummy.dir/a.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable dummy
[100%] Built target dummy
```

Note that the second time the cmake calls is on the subproject.

At the next call everything is even faster:

```
me@here:~/example/build$ make
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/example/build/subProject
[  0%] Built target subProjectTarget
Scanning dependencies of target dummy
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dummy.dir/a.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable dummy
[100%] Built target dummy
```

(Although here the file b.h is written every time causing a.cpp to be recompiled)

This stub can be very much improved by using cmake commands to generate the output directories (and not mkdir) and cascading the generator chosen for the main project (here I am assuming everything is using make)

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76171/discussion-on-answer-by-antonio-add-custom-command-update-dependency-list-ove).

Answer (score 0):

I think that `${codegenInputFiles}` should contain a list of hardcoded source files and include files required by the custom command. Documentation of [file(GLOB ...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html)  states:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from
>   your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is
>   added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to
>   ask CMake to regenerate.

The hard work (for which we are paid) is to keep the `${codegenInputFiles}` up to date (causing the full project rebuild). Anyway, you would have similar problem if someone created a new source file and hadn't added it to the `${codegenInputFiles}`, right? So I believe the additional dependency on include file should be treated the same.

Comment: GLOB is not used to create ${codegenInputFiles}. Codegen itself is always provided with a single file, which may include other files. Therefore, for generated sources to match their model, I need for cmake to watch for dependencies (i.e. the file i provided to codegen and other files it includes) and run codegen once any of dependencies get modified. However, I don`t see any way to adjust list of files to watch for once it was provided to add_custom_command. I need to do this if due to modification, include gets added or removed.

Comment: ${codegenInputFiles} is provided by custom cmake function that scans specified input file for any includes and recursively calls itself to handle complete dependency tree of a single codegen input file.

Comment: Some more info: there are multiple independent codegen invocations across the project, each having one inputFile (+its includes), corresponding sources and call to add_custom_command to setup denendencies with specific set of sources and specific set of inputs

Comment: "custom cmake function that scans specified input file for any includes and recursively calls" --> this is your function or some official CMake?

Comment: It is my function that understands DSL syntax, it simply called like XXDSL_GetModelDependencies(modelPath modelDeps), where modelPath - path to the root model file, which is passed to codegen

Comment: If ${codegenInputFiles} is created at configure time, you need to reconfigure build system to get the changes.

Comment: That`s exactly what I would like to avoid, as our previously used proprietary build system was more robust in this sense, allowing to update dependencies during build time.

Comment: Well, currently the most common use case is to update model files without changing includes. I can live with build system being not perfect and setup ugly strange rule "do a clean build if model includes set get changed". At least more common scenario with model files modifications (including one that get included) is already covered.