# Linking c++ files using CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, linker

Okay, so I just started dabbing into c++ and I'm hoping to get ahead on my classes in the fall but instead of using the a compiler I've been using nitrous.io as an IDE. Anyways long story short, I'm using CMakeLists.txt to compile and run but I've been running into a lot of difficulties when trying to link together an interface, it's corresponding cpp file and a main function.

Gradebook.h

```
//Gradebook.h
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

class Gradebook
{
  public:
    Gradebook(string n);
    Gradebook();
    void setCourse(string n);
    string getCourse();
    void displayMessage();

  private:
    string course;
};
```

Gradebook.cpp

```
//Gradebook.cpp
#include "Gradebook.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Gradebook::Gradebook(string n)
{
  course = n;
} 

Gradebook::Gradebook()
{
  cout << "Default constructor used." << endl;
} 

void Gradebook::setCourse(string n)
{
  course = n;
}

string Gradebook::getCourse()
{
  return course;
}

void Gradebook::displayMessage()
{
  cout << "Welcome to " << course << "'s gradebook." << endl;
}
```

GradebookRunner.cpp - main function

```
#include "Gradebook.h"

int main()
{
  Gradebook g("Intro to c++");
  g.displayMessage();
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt - I'm 95% sure that the syntax and linking is done correctly in the .h and .cpp files, this is where I believe I'm making the mistake.

```
##I've tried to use different combinations of Gradebook and Gradebook.cpp in here.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(Gradebook)
add_executable(Gradebook Gradebook.cpp)
```

Any help will be much appreciated :D

Comment: When I use GradebookRun.cpp in the CMakeLists file I get this error when compiling "GradebookRun.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `Gradebook::Gradebook(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'                                     
GradebookRun.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `Gradebook::displayMessage()' "

Comment: and when I use Gradebook.cpp in the CmakeLists file I get this error when compiling

(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Comment: `add_executable(Gradebook Gradebook.cpp GradebookRunner.cpp)`

Comment: When I change the preprocessor in GradebookRun.cpp to #include "Gradebook.cpp" it works perfectly, but that wasn't the way that the textbook showed. Fixed for now but would greatly appreciate any followup to getting the previous to work.

Comment: don't do that, try what I said.

Comment: There's also [a GLOB feature](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Process_Lots_Of_Input_Files) that can add all cpps in a directory for compilation for example.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add all files that belong to the executable (both headers and source files, so you have them all in IDE and dependencies are correctly resolved by CMake).

```
  add_executable(Gradebook Gradebook.cpp GradebookRunner.cpp Gradebook.h)
```

Note that [GLOB feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060061/2838364) could be tricky.