# Can you glob source code with meson?

Tags: build, build-system, meson-build

Is it possible to glob source code files in a meson build?

Answer (score 6):

Globbing source files is discouraged and is bad practice, and [not only on Meson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538444/518853). It causes weird errors, makes it hard to have some developement files aside for development but that you don't want to build or ship, and can cause problems with incremental builds.

Explicit is better than implicit.

**2021-03-02 EDIT:**

Read also [Why can't I specify target files with a wildcard?](https://mesonbuild.com/FAQ.html#why-cant-i-specify-target-files-with-a-wildcard) in the Meson FAQ.

> Meson does not support this syntax and the reason for this is simple. This can not be made both reliable and fast.

If after all the warnings, you still want to do it at your own risk, the FAQ tells you how in [But I really want to use wildcards!](https://mesonbuild.com/FAQ.html#but-i-really-want-to-use-wildcards). You just use an external script to do the globbing and return the list of files (that script is called `grabber.sh` in that example).

```
c = run_command('grabber.sh')
sources = c.stdout().strip().split('\n')
e = executable('prog', sources)
```

Answer (score 5):

I found an [example](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/blob/master/test%20cases/common/51%20file%20grabber/meson.build) in the meson unit tests showing how to glob source, but in the comments it says this is *not recommended*.

```
if build_machine.system() == 'windows'
  c = run_command('grabber.bat')
  grabber = find_program('grabber2.bat')
else
  c = run_command('grabber.sh')
  grabber = find_program('grabber.sh')
endif


# First test running command explicitly.
if c.returncode() != 0
  error('Executing script failed.')
endif

newline = '''
'''

sources = c.stdout().strip().split(newline)

e = executable('prog', sources)
```

**The reason this is not recommended:** attempting to add files by glob'ing a directory will NOT make those files automatically appear in the build. You have to *manually re-invoke* meson for the files to be added to the build. Re-invoking ninja or other back-ends is not sufficient, you must reinvoke meson itself.

Answer (score 5):

meson.build

```py
glob = run_command('python', 'glob')
sources = glob.stdout().strip().split('\n')
```

glob:

```py
import glob

sources = glob.glob('./src/*.cpp') + glob.glob('./src/**/*.cpp')
for i in sources:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Every sources have to be explicitly stated to build a target.

Comment: The only way I found was to call out to an external process that globs source and returns a list of files which can be iterated over in Meson.