# how can meson build specific directory

Tags: c, meson-build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msexE.png)

Assume that above situation, I configured meson build like the code below.

```
project('tutorial', ['c'], version : '1.0v')


src = files(['file1.c', 'file2.c', 'file3.c'])

executable('tutorial',
        sources : [src],
        c_args : [CFLAGS],
        link_args : [LDFLAGS, LDFLAGS_OUTPUT])
```

how can i specific directory build using regular expression like as

```
src = files(['*.c']) or
```

or useful meson fuction? (method)? like as

```
meson.src_dir('src/')
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a [subdir()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#subdir) function that you can use to "include" folder with another meson.build file.

```
src = ...

subdir('src')

executable(...)
```

In that sub-directory you should have separate *meson.build* file with files():

```
src += files('a.c', 'b.c')
```

- just file names, no need adding parent directory here
- you don't need brackets as [files function](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#files) accepts infinite number of arguments
- regular expressions, globbing are not supported by meson - this is to have defined result, i.e. no unexpected or implicit behavior.

**PS**

Regarding file globbing check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441673/can-you-glob-source-code-with-meson); apparently there is a workaround by running external shell scripts and using then result, but this is not recommended anyway (and most probably that's the reason why it's not possible with files() ): it wouldn't be possible for meson to notice added files - user needs to remember to re-run meson project build (which is long and not how it's meant to be), not just **ninja**.