# How to exclude files from glob with # or ~ at the beginning?

Tags: cmake

My editor always generates temp files like `#foo.cpp` or `~bar.cpp`.
How to exclude these files from my glob?

`file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_CPP ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} src/*.cpp src/*.cxx)`

Comment: It is not recommended to glob your source files. Look at this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027247/best-way-to-specify-sourcefiles-in-cmake

Comment: I know the disadvantage. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which characters a file should start with:

```
file(GLOB FILES [a-z]*.cpp)
```

This will match only files starting with a-z. If you have files starting with other characters like underscore just add it to the expression:

```
file(GLOB FILES [_a-z]*.cpp)
```