# Multi-Project cmake not working

Tags: c++, cmake, directory-structure

## My Situation

I`m trying to set up a project structure and the build scripts using `cmake` but I get an error
that my application is unable to find the header file that I try to include.

I hope that someone can guide me to a solution for this.

---

#### Current project

The project ist just an example reduced to one application and one library project. The goal is to 
have multiple clients and more than one library (some depending on each other).

`clients/Desktop` e.g. is an application making use of the `core/` library.

The image shows the project structure (screenshot from Visual Studio Code explorer)

[image: d]

Having a folder named like the project in the include folder is to change the includes from `Core.h`
to `Core/Core.h`. Or at least this was the plan. Maybe this is the problem?

Okay, so now the code:

`clients\Desktop\src\main.cpp`:

```
#include "Core/Core.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ProjectStructure::Core::Example ex;
    ex.sayHello();
}
```

`Core\include\Core\Core.h`:

```
#ifndef PROJECTSTRUCTURE_CORE_CORE_H
#define PROJECTSTRUCTURE_CORE_CORE_H

#include <iostream>

namespace ProjectStructure {
namespace Core {

class Example {
public:
    void sayHello();
};

} // namespace Core
} // namespace ProjectStructure 

#endif
```

`Core\src\Core.cpp`:

```
#include "Core/Core.h"

namespace ProjectStructure {
namespace Core {

void Example::sayHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello world.";
}

} // namespace Core
} // namespace ProjectStructure
```

`clients\Desktop\include\CMakeLists.txt`:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("Desktop")
```

`clients\Desktop\src\CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(APP_HEADERS
)

SET(APP_SOURCES
"main.cpp"
)

# Make executable
ADD_EXECUTABLE("${PROJECT_NAME}" "${APP_SOURCES}")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES("${PROJECT_NAME}" "Core")
```

`clients\Desktop\CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Version check
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Project
PROJECT("Desktop" CXX)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("include")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("src")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("test")
```

`clients\CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Executables
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("${PROJECTSTRUCTURE_CLIENTS_DIR}/Desktop")
```

`Core\include\CMakeLists.txt`:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("Core")
```

`Core\src\CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(LIB_HEADERS
"../include/Core/Core.h"
)

SET(LIB_SOURCES
"Core.cpp"
)

# Make library
ADD_LIBRARY("${PROJECT_NAME}" STATIC "${LIB_SOURCES}")

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES("${PROJECT_NAME}" PROPERTIES
FRAMEWORK FALSE
PUBLIC_HEADER "${LIB_HEADERS}"
)

INSTALL(TARGETS "${PROJECT_NAME}"
EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets"
ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib COMPONENT libs
RUNTIME DESTINATION bin COMPONENT libs
LIBRARY DESTINATION lib COMPONENT libs
PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME} COMPONENT devel
INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
```

`Core\CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Version check
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.5)

# Project
PROJECT("Core" CXX)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("include")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("src")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("test")
```

And last but not least the top level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Version check
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.5)

# Project
PROJECT("ProjectStructure" CXX)

# Status
MESSAGE(STATUS "Cmake running...")
MESSAGE(STATUS "System: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "System: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}") 
MESSAGE(STATUS "Cmake-Version: ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "C++ compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")

# Project structure
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

SET(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build")
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")

SET(PROJECTSTRUCTURE_CLIENTS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/clients")

# Prohibit in source builds
IF("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
MESSAGE(SEND_ERROR "In-source builds are not allowed. Remove generated files.")
ENDIF()

# Output settings
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
SET(CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE   ON)

# Build mode
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)                      # Dev
#SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)            # Test
#SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)                   # Release

# Used features
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) # -std=c++14
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Compiler flags
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g3 -O0")             # Dev
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O3")        # Test
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")               # Release

# Libraries
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/core")

# Executables
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("${PROJECTSTRUCTURE_CLIENTS_DIR}")
```

I'm using out of source builds using the following commands:

```
cd build
cmake .. -G "MSYS Makefiles"
```

And then run using:

```
make
```

**Note:** The real project is also containing directories for documentation and some other things.
Also files like `.gitignore` and a `.travis.yml` (but that is the next thing I have to get working).

---

#### The problem:

The `cmake`command is working but the `make`command tells me that the included file (`Core.h`) could
not be found.
I think the problem is in the part where the library gets installed. But I was unable to find the
right way to do it. The solution I posted here is only one from many that I tried.

---

#### Additional questions:

**1.** The *CMakeLists* marked with an *A* are empty. They where just added so that every directory
has a *CMakeLists* file. Should i remove them?

**2.** I would like to use google-test/mock in my projects with tests for each project in the
`project/test` folder. I it enough to include google test in the top level *CMakeLists* to make this
work or do I have to include it in each sub project?

**3.** Is it good practice to list the source files or to automatically load them? I think listing
them is better even if it is more work. I think this has also advantages for `cmake` when reloading
the project. Is this also true for tests? I am thinking about making a test file for each source
file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be the problem with the installation part. I think there is a problem with the way you add include directories. :)

When you use INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES you say that cmake should add proper flags for compiler for files in this CMakeLists. But NOT in files added in parent CMakeLists. I think the stack is a great analogy for this situation. (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/include_directories.html)

Note that you added `./Core/CMakeLists.txt` in `./CMakeLists.txt`:`ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/core")`, `./Core/include` is no more in use when you add the clients subdirectory later.

IMHO the most elegant solution is to use
`TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(Core PUBLIC pathToCoresHeaders)` instead. If you decide to use it, the line `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES("${PROJECT_NAME}" "Core")` will add proper include paths to desktop executable.

AD1. Yes, I think that you should remove them. You can leave the CMakeLists.txt in `test`'s directories as it usually takes one more targets for UT.

AD2. I would recommend adding it in top level directory before you start to define own targets, and the link your testing execs with `gtest` and `gtest_main`, this should register gtest's include paths.

AD3. I list all my files in cmake. I'd rather see error about missing file than unresolved external symbol at the end of build. But it is not black and white ([Specify source files globally with GLOB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1027247)). You should make your own decision and live with consequences.

PS1. I would suggest to additionally test your build on some unix like system, because Windows is way too liberal with the case insensitivity.

There are the changes I would have done to improve your build system.

`./Core/CMakeLists.txt`

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.5)

PROJECT(Core CXX)

SET(INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
SET(SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

SET(LIB_HEADERS
    ${INCLUDE_DIRS}/Core/Core.h
)

SET(LIB_SOURCES
    ${SOURCE_DIR}/Core.cpp
)

# Make library
ADD_LIBRARY("${PROJECT_NAME}" STATIC ${LIB_SOURCES} ${LIB_HEADERS})

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES("${PROJECT_NAME}" PROPERTIES
FRAMEWORK FALSE
PUBLIC_HEADER "${LIB_HEADERS}"
)

INSTALL(TARGETS "${PROJECT_NAME}"
EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets"
ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib COMPONENT libs
RUNTIME DESTINATION bin COMPONENT libs
LIBRARY DESTINATION lib COMPONENT libs
PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME} COMPONENT devel
INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(test)
```

`./clients/Desktop/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project("Desktop" CXX)

SET(SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
SET(INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

SET(APP_HEADERS
)

SET(APP_SOURCES
    ${SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
)

# Make executable
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${APP_SOURCES} ${APP_HEADERS})
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} Core)

add_subdirectory(test)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Building works now. I'm now working on setting up the google test support. About the part with the testing on linux. I plan to do this using travis (I i get it to work). Only one question. The bin dir in my project seems to be unused. My plan was to have the compiled application in there at the end. Is this possible or should i remove it?

Comment: @FrTerstappen You may consider using https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html to put your binaries in one directory. I would rather use `ctest` to execute tests https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest and install https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html to deploy your application.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm currently trying to get google-test to work in my project. I think i will go with the option you recommend even if the first look at the links made me feel a bit overwhelmed. I think that this is more complicated than it should be considering that testing a important aspect.