# CMake: add all files on current directory and subdirectories with target_sources()

Tags: c++, cmake

In our C++ project, we have several CMakeLists.txt files (on different directories) listing every single cpp file desired with `target_sources()`.

For example:

```
target_sources(<Project> PUBLIC
    foo_1.cpp
    foo_2.cpp
    foo_3.cpp
)
```

This is fine in case we have few source files, but it's becoming harder for those directories where we have multiple cpp files to be added.

Is there a simple way to tell `target_resources()` to add all files on directory and subdirectories where CMakeList.txt file is?

For example, placing a CMakeLists.txt on a directory with multiple files and sub-directories (with more files) that just adds everything contained there.

Comment: You can but it's not recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027247/is-it-better-to-specify-source-files-with-glob-or-each-file-individually-in-cmak

Answer (score 2):

This is solving my problem:

```
file(GLOB SRC_FILES    
    "*.cpp"
)

target_sources(<project> PUBLIC
    ${SRC_FILES}
)
´´´
```

Comment: If you use this [`GLOB`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem) command, you should at least add `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`. It can help avoid some of the unintended or non-obvious consequences of using this command.