# Make all files in a folder accessible to all projects (subdirectories)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I have multiple projects (subdirectories) inside my repository. All projects have only one executable file named `main.cpp` and they all use libraries from the `common` folder with `#include` statements. The folder structure looks like this:

```
root
|
├────common
|    ├──── example.h
|    ├──── example.cpp
|    ├──── *.h          # many header files
|    └──── *.cpp        # many source files
|
├────Project_A
|    ├──── CMakeLists.txt
|    └──── main.cpp
|
├────Project_B
|    ├──── CMakeLists.txt
|    └──── main.cpp
|
└──── CMakeLists.txt
```

This is my attempt at writing the *root's CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("root")

file(GLOB_RECURSE CommonLibs ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common/*.cpp)
link_libraries(${CommonLibs})

add_subdirectory ("Project_A")
add_subdirectory ("Project_B")
```

*Project_A's CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
add_executable (Project_A "main.cpp")
```

*Project_B's CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
add_executable (Project_B "main.cpp")
```

However when running any of the projects I get this error:

```
LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x7AC, file example.h
```

I don't believe the file is corrupted because before I tried to use `link_libraries()` in root's CMakeLists.txt I was getting other error:

```
Unresolved external symbol SomeNamespace::ExampleClass::ExampleClass(bool)
```

## Possible duplicates

Other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921695/how-can-i-build-a-c-project-with-multiple-interdependent-subdirectories) don't solve my problem because they usually work with a more complex folder structure. Also there are questions that attempt to target only single project like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540624/cmake-add-all-files-on-current-directory-and-subdirectories-with-target-sources), but I have multiple projects.

Can you please provide a concise solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `CMakeLists.txt` to your `common/` directory:

```
root
|
├────common
|    ├──── CMakeLists.txt <-------- Add this
|    ├──── example.h
....
```

**common/CMakeLists.txt**

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE CommonLibsFiles ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SRC_DIR}/*.cpp)
add_library(CommonLibs ${CommonLibsFiles})
...
```

**root's CMakeLists.txt**

```
...

### NO NEED FOR THESE
file(GLOB_RECURSE CommonLibs ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common/*.cpp)
link_libraries(${CommonLibs})
###

add_subdirectory(common) #CommonLibs will now be visible to children directories
...
```

Now link the libraries as required. For example for *project A*:

**Project_A's CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
add_executable (Project_A "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(Project_A PRIVATE CommonLibs) #link to common libs here,
```

All the targets/variables that are created or are visible to *parent* cmake file, are visible to children. The reverse is not true though. For children to expose their variables to parent, they need to explicitly specify `PARENT_SCOPE`

Comment: I tried this but two errors emerged: `CMake Error at common/CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_library): Cannot find source file: CommonLibsFiles - Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx` And this one: `CMake Error at common/CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_library): No SOURCES given to target: CommonLibs`

Comment: Ah, you have to wrap it in braces, `${CommonLibsFiles}`

Answer (score 2):

The following lines in your top-level CMake do not make much sense:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE CommonLibs ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common/*.cpp)
link_libraries(${CommonLibs})
```

The `link_libraries()` command accepts **libraries** or **library targets**, not variables (such as `CommonLibs`). You can *use* the `CommonLibs` variable to define a new library target, then link the library **target** to your executables using `link_libraries()`:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE CommonLibs ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common/*.cpp)
# Add this line.
add_library(MyCommonLib SHARED ${CommonLibs})
link_libraries(MyCommonLib)
```

Please note that the use of [`link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_libraries.html) in general is *discouraged*, even in CMake documentation itself. You should prefer linking your `MyCommonLib` to the **specific** executables that require it using `target_link_libraries`.

```
target_link_libraries(Project_A PRIVATE MyCommonLib)
```