# Android NDK CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, linker-errors

I am trying to compile Bitcoin (Core) for Android using Android NDK in Android Studio, but I get a `CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: bitcoin`. I cloned the [Bitcoin repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) into `app/src/main/cpp/bitcoin`. My `CMakeLists.txt` (in `app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt`) is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(bitcoin)
add_library(bitcoin SHARED bitcoin/src/)
```

I tried many solutions from this forum, including appending `C CXX` and `CXX` to the project name, adding an `include_directories(bitcoin/src/)`, adding a `set_target_properties(bitcoin PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)`, and various combinations of these, but the error persists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just giving a `add_library` a source directory isn't going to work AFAIK. You're supposed to list every source file that should be built. [There are alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027247/is-it-better-to-specify-source-files-with-glob-or-each-file-individually-in-cmak), but I'm not sure whether they are considered good practice.

Comment: Strange that the [Android NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake) doesn't mention that. I tried:

`file(GLOB BITCOIN_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS /bitcoin/src/.cpp /bitcoin/src/.h /bitcoin/src/*.hpp)
add_library(bitcoin SHARED ${BITCOIN_FILES})`

but this doesn't work. Should I call a separate `add_library(...)` for every `.cpp` file?

Comment: The globbing pattern `/bitcoin/src/*.cpp` means that files will be searched under **absolute path** `/bitcoin/src/`. For search files relative to the source directory, do not use forward slash: `bitcoin/src/*.cpp`.

Comment: _"the Android NDK documentation doesn't mention that"_ That page only has examples with a single source file.  _"Should I call a separate add_library(...) for every .cpp file?"_ No.