# CMake way of wildcard values on set variables

Tags: c++, cmake, include, c++20

I have the next snippet on a CMake based project

```
set(Headers
    ./include/MyLib/main.hpp
)
set(Sources
    src/main.cpp
)

add_library(${This} STATIC ${Headers} ${Sources})
```

How can I indicate to recursively include all the interface files under the:

- `./include/MyLib/{ /* File name here */  }.ixx`

and all the source files under the

- `src/{ /* File name here */ }.cpp`

Comment: Using globbing in CMake for this purpose is usually no good idea. See [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060061/7703564).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to replace set() by:

```
file(
  GLOB_RECURSE
  Headers
  ./include/MyLib/*.ixx
)
```

and same thing for your source files.

Comment: Works perfectly!